# How do I fix error: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' in gradle bootRun?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

> I get an error when i run gradle bootRun
>
> Steins-MacBook-Air:component steinkorsveien$ gradle bootRun
>
> > Task :bootRun
>
> .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __
>   _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \  \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )   '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / / 
>   =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.7.RELEASE)
>
> > Task :bootRun FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>
>   > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   >     finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 22s 3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
>   Steins-MacBook-Air:component steinkorsveien$
>
> My Build.gradle is

```
plugins{
  id 'java'
  id 'checkstyle' 
  id 'jacoco'
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8"
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.3.0.RELEASE"
}

group = 'org.steinko'

sonarqube {
    properties {
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonarcloud.io"
        property "sonar.login", "43983a01ea79d77e7ce4931e989733cdcfb6ef47"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "Bank"
        property "sonar.organization", "steinko-github"
    property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"
        property "sonar.java.source", "13"
    }
  }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal" } 
}

sourceSets {
    intTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
        intTestComile.extendsFrom testCompile
    intTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.7.RELEASE'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
  implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.3'
  implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.7'

    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'

    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:4.3.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.7.RELEASE') 

    testCompile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian', name: 'arquillian-bom', version: '1.7.0.Alpha1', ext: 'pom'
    testImplementation 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.7.0.Alpha1'
    testImplementation 'org.arquillian.cube:arquillian-cube-docker:1.18.2'
  testImplementation 'org.arquillian.cube:assertj-docker-java:1.18.2'
  testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.16.1'


    intTestImplementation 'io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:4.3.0'
    intTestImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.7.RELEASE') 

    intTestCompile  group: 'org.jboss.arquillian', name: 'arquillian-bom', version: '1.7.0.Alpha1', ext: 'pom'
    intTestImplementation 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.7.0.Alpha1'
    intTestImplementation 'org.arquillian.cube:arquillian-cube-docker:1.18.2'
  intTestImplementation 'org.arquillian.cube:assertj-docker-java:1.18.2'
  intTestImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.16.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
  source = sourceSets.main.allJava
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.intTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest

project.tasks["sonarqube"].dependsOn "jacocoTestReport"

test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
integrationTest.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

checkstyleTest.enabled = false
checkstyleIntTest.enabled = false
```

> How do I fix this error?
>
> The stacktrace are:
>   * Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
>           at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:203)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
>           at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
>           at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
>           at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
>           at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:417)
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:40)
>           at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:132)
>           at org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun.exec(BootRun.java:83)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:727)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:694)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:568)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:553)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:536)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:276)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:265)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
>           at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:192)

Comment: First you should do what the tip in the output suggests (`Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`)

Comment: I do not se any new information in the stakctrace

Comment: The last stack trace is just the one where Gradle informs you that your application failed to run. You need to look in the output from the application to (hopefully) see why. As it is a runtime error, it can be anything. Maybe Spring can't autowire a bean for you, maybe a runtime dependency is missing, maybe there was an uncaught application exception. If the output from Gradle is confusing, you could also just run the application directly with `java -jar build/libs/myproject.jar` (substitute with the actual name) and it should fail in the same way but with a direct log output.